# enclosure parameter in fputcsv not behaving as expected

Tags: php

This I believe has a simple explanation, I just cannot see it.  I want to generate a pretty simple csv  delimetered file with double quotes around field values.

As per [the manual page on fputcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php), I try to pass on the delimiter and enclosure argument explicitly to have double-quoted field values required for data import in third-party application as in function call below:

```
    // relevant line of codes ...
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

        $name_pieces = "";  
        $name_pieces = explode(" ", $row['name']);  

        $numberOfPieces = count($name_pieces);

        $lastNameIndex = $numberOfPieces - 1;

        $lastname = $name_pieces[$lastNameIndex];
        $firstname = $name_pieces[0];

 }   // Line array becomes the first, second, third fields in resulting .csv output.

    $line = array( $row['username'], 
                   $row['name'], 
                   $firstname,
                   $lastname,
                   $row['description'] );

 $data[] = $line;

}        
foreach($data as $dataLine){
    if(fputcsv($fh, $dataLine, ',', '"') === false){
      die("Unable to write to csv file.");
    }
}
```

Following is a sample of the script's .csv output, notice that only second and last fields are quoted.

```
AG,"Alan Gaulois",Alan,Gaulois,"(AG) Alan Gaulois"
COMMIS,commis,commis,commis,"(COMMIS) commis"
DU,"Denis Fargo",Denis,Fargo,"(DF) Denis Fargo"
```

Anyone have an idea why the fields are not all quoted? I could well have missed something on doc page, any insight appreciated!

Comment: Err... because not all fields have spaces?

Comment: @Ignacio I thought the enclosure argument, in fputcsv() was to add quotes around field values.

Comment: Quotes are optional for most CSV implementations. In fact only fields conaining commas are required to be enclosed/escaped that way. -- Why does it matter?

Comment: The linked documentation doesn't say that.

Comment: @mario You are right it may not even matter, I was expecting to get all field values quoted, thinking it was the needed behavior in a .csv file as there is such an option in importation script I am using. I shall find out soon enough if it really matters at all having quoted field values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my knowledge, yes, delimiters are only needed if there are spaces, if you need something else, consider using `array_map`.

Something like:

```
function surroundWithQuotes ($input)
{
    $input = str_replace('"', '""', $input); //escaping in csv files is done by doing the same quote twice, odd
    return '"' . $input . '"';
}

foreach($data as $dataLine){
    if(fputcsv($fh, array_map("surroundWithQuotes" $dataLine),$dataLine, ',', '') === false){
      die("Unable to write to csv file.");
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work, because in CSV a `"` isn't encoded as `\"` but as `""`.

Comment: I noticed that when I was looking at the csv documentation, and corrected it.  Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: This is a  truly cool idea, but if string value has no spaces maybe I don't even need this? Why the empty enclosure argument? I was thinking of just adding trim() to the code and try if the unquoted values get imported properly in 3rd party application.

Comment: Like the comment above said, this isn't needed to be csv compliant, but if you wanted to, you could use this (to make it more human readable, etc.

Comment: Turns out I will be using your function after all, as the csv need to be all quoted for 3rd party import script to do it's thing. I may need to adjust for strings that are already quoted, will check this out tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: That is why I added it, had the same problem with a 3rd party program.  Why can't we all just use one spec?

Answer (score 2):

the function just sets quotes, if necessary. If there is no space, special char or quote inside the string you want to write, no enclosing quotes are needed.

The `$enclosure` argument doesn't tell the parser "you have to quote everything", but it tells the parser, which char to use to quote (by default it *is* `"`, so you don't have to write it).

Answer (score 0):

There's something missing in the above mentioned answers, the predicate or call back function would return "" in case of an empty string.

Ideally it should be.

```
function encloseWithQuotes($value)
{
    if (empty($value)) {
        return "";
    }
    $value = str_replace('"', '""', $value);
    return '"'.$value.'"';
}
```